# Ln differenced price level times 400, why 400?

Tags: inflation, time-series

I am replicating a [2001 Journal of Economic Perspectives methodology paper on Vector Autoregression by James H. Stock and Adam Watson](http://dx.doi.org/10.1257/jep.15.4.101). The paper can be found here: http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/stck_watson_var.pdf

I'm having a slight problem with the log differencing. In the paper the researchers state that they multiply the ln differenced price levels by 400.

I have no clue why this is done. The price level data is quarterly chain-weighted and seasonally adjusted implicit GDP deflator of the US. I would understand if they would multiply by four to get the annual inflation figures, but this is unclear. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: There is an unanswered question on that some study in the cross validated stack exchange: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142511/svar-with-taylor-rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already accounted for multiplication by 4. Further multiplication by 100 to make the units of measurement percentage points? I.e. inflation is usually referred to as 3%, not as 0.03.

Comment: Of course! Cheers, I feel like an imbecile!

Comment: @KukkoPärssinen I have heard this question before :) If it solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the green check on its left.